# Python: Function that takes a list and a separator and returns a string

Tags: python

I need to create a function that takes a list and a separator value as parameters and returns the string representation of the list which is separated by the separator value.

The only built-in functions I can use are `range()` and `str()` without any slice expressions, list methods or string methods.

I have put together some code but I know it isn't right as it is displaying a space at the beginning and the separator at the end (separator needs to be only between values).

How can I fix this?

```
def my_string(my_list, sep=', '):
    string = " "

    for words in my_list:
        string += words + ', '     

    return string

my_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]
list_string = my_string(my_list, sep=', ')
print (list_string)
```

Comment: FWIW, for the record, the actual real world every day solution to this would be `return sep.join(my_list)`…

Comment: You should use `sep` if your passing it into the function.

Comment: @deceze you are right, however OP explicitly stated that it is not allowed to use function from `string`.

Comment: Can you use `len()`?

Comment: @Max I know. I was just stating this for future visitors.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without any built-in functions:

```
def my_string(my_list, sep=', '):
    result = ''

    # Safety check
    if not my_list:
        return result

    idx = 0
    for word in my_list:
        # Add the seperator before every item but the first one
        result += (sep if idx else '') + word
        idx += 1

    return result

my_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]
list_string = my_string(my_list)
print (list_string)  # >>> 'item1, item2, item3, item4'
```

Few points:

- As [RoadRunner said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276387/python-function-that-takes-a-list-and-seperator-and-returns-a-string/53276488#comment93434878_53276387), You should have used `sep` inside the function `my_string`.
- No need to pass `sep` if it is the default value
- Personally, I don't like names that start with `my_`, it should be meaningful. Why not `join_list` for the function and `l` or `arr` or even `_list` for the parameter?

Comment: `enumerate` is a built in method. OP can't use any built in except `range` and `str`

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple, join everything except the last word, then add the last word at the end:

```
# Calculates the length of a list
def my_len(my_list):
    length = 0

    for _ in my_list:
        length += 1

    return length

def my_string(my_list, sep=', '):
    string = ""
    length = my_len(my_list)

    # Loop through indices except last
    for i in range(length - 1):
        string += my_list[i] + sep

    # Add last item on
    string += my_list[i+1]

    return string

my_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]
list_string = my_string(my_list, sep=', ')
print (list_string)
# item1, item2, item3, item4
```

**Note:** Since it seems from your requirements you can't use `len()`, you need to make your own custom function `my_len()` to do this.

Even though this works, in the real world you want to use `sep.join(my_list)`.

Comment: Brilliant idea to implement your own `len` method! However I believe `some_list[some_index]` would count as a list method? Not 100% on that

Comment: @The That's why questions with such arbitrary restrictions are… less than helpful really.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Thats true. I assumed that the OP would be allowed to index lists. A list method IMO is `list.append()`, `list.extend()` etc. Indexing is part of the language constructs for Python, and many other languages.

Comment: @RoadRunner Yeah, but `some_list[some_index]` is just a nice way to say `some_list.__getitem__(some_index)`.

Comment: @MaxPowers Good point. But that gets called under the hood from Python? The Python interpreter takes `some_list[some_index]` and calls `some_list.__getitem__(some_index)` instead. I'm not sure if that counts. That would just be silly if indexing is restricted from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_string(my_list, separator=", "):
    string = ""
    disp_separator = False
    for i in my_list:
        string += separator if disp_separator else "" # don't display the separator the first time
        string += str(i)
        disp_separator = True
    return string
```

input : `my_string(["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"])`
output : `'item1, item2, item3, item4'`

input : `my_string([1, 2, 3, 4], separator=' | ')` 
output : `'1 | 2 | 3 | 4'`

Work with any type who can be convert with str() builtin

Comment: This produces an TypeError on the 6th line and does not return anything.

Comment: sorry, i write ``my_list`` insead of ``i``, i fixed that

Answer (score -4):

Its simple you can use 'join' which is inbuilt function in python.

```html
def my_string(my_list, sep=', '):
    return sep.join(my_list)

my_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]
list_string = my_string(my_list, sep=', ')
print (list_string)
```

Comment: OP said he can't use any string methods. I.E `.join`